# no read permission on 'MSysObjects'

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I want to use MS Access in my project.  I try to integrate with this code.

```
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM MSysObjects where database <> ''");
```

By using this I try to get all the table names from `MSysObjects`. But I get an error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]
>   Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Please help me resolve this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To connect with MS Access with read permission follow the following steps:

Open MS access 
1. click 
"Office Button" => access option =>  trust center => trust center settings => Macro settings => Enable macros => Ok

1. From your access file Press ctrl+g
   in that create a macro by pressing run symbol. create a macro in any name.

Inside that :
paste these lines

strDdl = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

save this... and run your macro. 
Finnaly you had granted select permission on "MySysObject".

Comment: This is just the same as the accepted answer, except ~15 hours later and not as well-written.

Answer (score 5):

Give the *Admin* user read (`SELECT`) permission on `MSysObjects`.

In an Access session, open the Immediate window (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>), construct a DDL `GRANT` statement and execute it from `CurrentProject.Connection`

```vb
strDdl = "GRANT SELECT ON MSysObjects TO Admin;"
CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl
```

Note that statement must be executed from ADO.  It should work as written because `CurrentProject.Connection` is an ADO object.  However it will fail if attempted with a DAO `Execute` method such as `CurrentDb.Execute` or when run from the Access query designer.