# Getting the table structure in ms access with SQL query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, table-structure

How to get the table structure in MS Access with a SQL query?

Using the following query:

```
SELECT name FROM MSysObjects
```

Results in the following exception:

> Exception: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Record(s) cannot be read; no read permission on 'MSysObjects'.

Comment: Are you after table names and column names?

Comment: You shouldn't add "urgent" to your questions, it has the opposite effect - it makes people ignore the question instead. Have a read through [this paper](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) on how to better ask technical questions.

Comment: yes kareem......i actually neeed the table structure so that i can create the access db to postgres

Comment: These may help: 
http://harborsparrow.blogspot.com/2009/05/c-code-to-get-schema-of-access-table.html and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699897/retrieve-list-of-tables-in-ms-access-file

Comment: I just noticed the Java tag, whereas the provided links are for c#. Sourry about that. Good luck.

Comment: kareem....  i using java...can u help me in java

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know java.

Comment: its ok kareemm....thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [This](http://www.perfectparadigm.com/tip001.html)

```
SELECT * FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type=1 AND Flags=0
```

Ms Access has several system tables that are, by default, hidden from tables list. You can show them.

In Ms Access 2007 do a right click on tables list and select Navigation Options. At the bottom of the form you will find Show System Objects check box. Check it and system tables will show up in tables list. They all start with MSys.
Alternatively, options form can be activated from application menu - click button Access options -> select Current Database and there is Navigation Options button.

Now you can examine structure and contents and generate queries of all system tables with MsAccess tools.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629211/can-we-list-all-tables-in-msaccess-database-using-sql)

Comment: vignesh...previous link does nt give the table structure....i actually neeed the table structure so that i can create the access db to postgres....through java....

Comment: PerfectParadigm.com is for sale, the "This" link does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Set up an ODBC connection for your postrgres database and then call the transfer database command for each of your tables.

Comment: From first quick reading, I guess that this is the only answer. If you do not have the linked table in your data sources, you cannot run queries against it. Once you made the ODBC connection file to reach the needed database (one file for each db), see for TSQL for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/connect-to-an-odbc-data-source-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-ver16, you can choose the system table from the list. After having added the linked tables, you can start the query designer, make a data model and run SQL on it.

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the permissions issue for MSysObjects, see these similar questions:
[no read permission on 'MSysObjects'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971082/no-read-permission-on-msysobjects), or 
[Run C# queries against (hidden) system tables in Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23625427/run-c-sharp-queries-against-hidden-system-tables-in-access)