# MS Access Migration to MySQL Connect to Source Error

Tags: ms-access, migration, mysql-workbench

I am currently in the process of migrating my Access 2019 database to a MySQL server.

I have tried a number of different avenues, but ultimately when using the MySQL Workbench Migration Wizard, I get the following error log:

```
Connect to source DBMS...
- Connecting...
Connecting to ...
Opening ODBC connection to DSN=LSCBDPORTAL...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\db_msaccess_re_grt.py", line 701, in connect
    return MsAccessReverseEngineering.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\db_msaccess_re_grt.py", line 152, in connect
    con = db_driver.connect(connection, password)
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\db_driver.py", line 95, in connect
    connection = library.connect(connection_string, password=password)
pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 71, in run
    self.func()
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration_schema_selection.py", line 172, in task_connect
    if not self.main.plan.migrationSource.connect():
  File "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\modules\migration.py", line 199, in connect
    self._rev_eng_module.connect(self.connection, self.password or "")
SystemError: Error("('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')"): error calling Python module function DbMsAccessRE.connect
ERROR: Error during Connect to source DBMS: Error("('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')"): error calling Python module function DbMsAccessRE.connect
ERROR: Exception in task 'Connect to source DBMS': SystemError('Error("(\'HY000\', \'The driver did not supply an error!\')"): error calling Python module function DbMsAccessRE.connect',)

Failed
```

I expected to have this work seamlessly because of how simple this database is. I must be configuring something wrong early in the migration process.

Comment: Apparently, mysql workbench cannot connect to your ms access database. Since it is not you writing the code, there is not too much you can do about it, but to raise a bug report.

Comment: @LegitshipCBD71 - Just a hunch: Try executing the GRANT statement described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19971579/2144390) and then try the migration again. The "reverse engineering" code may be trying to read the MSysObjects system table.

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys. I actually uninstalled the latest Access Database Engine and reverted back to version 14.x. That allowed me to migrate it into MySQL with errors that I think are tied to the relationships within my Access data base.

Answer (score -1):

1. go to control panel /uninstall all access 2016 or 2010 engine
2. open MS access then close it
3. start migration